# Popping up a alert in front of react native Modal hangs up the application in ios

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native

I was trying to make some authentication system in which after click on sign up user is asked for otp. I made a modal for Otp using modal tag which only get visible when some value becomes true. Whenever user submits a otp i open up a alert box saying sign in now and change that modal visibile to false.
But while doing this I faced a problem in Ios. This is working fine in android but while trying with ios device phone hangs up on modal screen and does not go back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a quite known problem with modals and alert since the `alert` itself is a form of modal(overlay item) and `setState` occurs asynchronous so the actions kind of block each other and the whole UX gets hung.You need to do is just synchronize the OTP modal closing and alerting.

**Edited:** Better add timeout to your alert using `setTimeOut(()=>Alert.alert(), 0);`

The code should look like that:

```
this.setState({
  isOTPModalVisible: false
}, () => {
   Alert.alert('message');
})
```